# Ubuntu get elapsed time

Tags: boot, time

Hello how can i view the system elapsed time ? Example: ubuntu is turned on at 10:00 now it would be 12:00 , elapsed time is : 2 hours how can i get this information ?

Comment: @user000001 answer with the command and a source link.

Comment: @Tomas you've asked 4 out of a total of 8 questions today. Since much of what you ask is easily searchable, I recommend you slow down and use Google more often. If you ask too many questions, you may eventually be banned from doing so (automated system -- good answers\edits are needed to remove it -- mods cannot lift it).

Comment: @Zacharee1: It looks like it wasn't a good idea to answer after all, because now the answer is downvoted :(

Comment: @user000001 hmm. People aren't meant to download answers to bad or closed questions.

Comment: @user000001 I'm giving you an upvote because you did your research.

Answer (score 0):

To see how long the system is running since last boot, you can use the `uptime` command.

Some other commands are `last reboot` or `who -b`.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131775/how-long-has-my-linux-system-been-running